# Computation of a point location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector-grid, select-by-location, atlas

I created grids (A1, A2....,B1,B2,...etc.) in print layout (main properties-grids). I also use atlas. I display many points and I need to calculate location of every point within a page of atlas and a grid. It is simple to calculate location of a point within a page atlas, because atlas is driven by a grid layer. I don´t know how to simply calculate location of a point within a grid.
On a picture below black line is atlas grid frame (overlapping), red line are grids created at print layout

How can be it done?
[image]

Comment: I suggest you add some images which show, what you are looking for, and tell us, where the calculation location should "go".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "location of every point within a page of atlas and a grid"? Like A1, B3 etc.? Please also show how/where you create the black and red grid. And finally, as @Erik mentioned: where should the result be displayed or saved?

Comment: What do you want to do with the coordinates?

Comment: I created black grid as a vector grid (vector - research tools - vector grid). Red grid is created at print layout (map-main properties-grids). I mean to find out location of every point in A1, B2 etc. The result should be displayed at attribute table of a vector grid layer used for atlas. If a result is displayed elsewhere, I don´t mind.

Comment: I think you can not access to your gird created on your map in the layout to analyse with points. The only option you have is to create a real layer like you black one which would serve as location layer for your point. Is it fine for your use case ?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Unfortunately, it needs a lot of manual work.

Comment: @pazelvak I did find a way to do it ! I hope it would be clear enough. Ask me if needed.

Comment: @Corentin Lemaitre  I tried your solution and it doesnt work. Can we please discuss what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution but this need that your gird have always the same number of division of your final layout (always 5 division horizontal and 4 vertical). If you want to change it you only have to adapt the expression.

### Principle

The goal is to calculate the position of the point in your layout based on the coordinate of your point and the map extent.
For example : you have a point that have Y coordinate = 105.
If your map max Y is 110 and min Y is 100 then your point will be in the center.  If it is in the center then you should attribute the letter in the middle, if you go form `A` to `E` it should be `C`.

I assume you have 4 divisions in X with number from 1 to 4 and 5 division in Y with letter from A to E.

### Expression

0. Make sure the layer for your points is in the same CRS as you are using for your layout. In your layout name your map item `Carte 1` or change the name in the expression.
1. Add an `attribute table` with your point layer and set it to get only visible features.
2. Add a column with the heading X and with the attribute based on the following expression :

```
with_variable( 'extent',
               map_get( item_variables( 'Carte 1' ), 'map_extent' ), 
               ceil(($x -x_min(@extent)) / bounds_width(@extent)*4)
)
```

3. Add a column with the heading Y and with the attribute based on the following expression :

```
with_variable( 'extent',
               map_get( item_variables( 'Carte 1' ), 'map_extent' ), 
               char(64+ceil(($y -y_min(@extent)) / bounds_height(@extent)*5))
)
```

### Result

[image]

### Notes

The function `with variable()` define a temporary variable named `extent` to be used easier in the calculation.

The function `ceil()` permit to get 1 when we are between 0 and 1, 2 between 1 and 2.

The function `char()` is used to get letter based on asci code. If you do `char(65)` you get A, `char (66)` you get B. Combine with ceil it permit to get the letter you want based on number.